# Absolute value on both sides equation

Tags: functions

I have a question:

Solve

$ 2 - |x+1| = |4x-3| $

The answers are 4/5, 2/3.

I understand why one of the answers is 4/5 but what I dont understand is why its 2/3.

I created three regions for the solutions:

$x\ge 3/4$

$x<-1$

$-1\le x < 3/4$

The first two regions are correct, but the last one is not. So then why is 2/3's a solution?

I keep getting questions like this wrong and at first i though i knew why but again I'm stumped. Please help me.

Comment: Did you check the equation for $x=2/3$? Then we have $1/3=|-1/3|$, so where is the problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I dont understand why 2/3 can be a solution if the region −1<<3/4 is does not work?

Comment: What has modulus to do with your problem?

Comment: @Bernard in the equation i used the modulus, therefore it IS the problem. A value with a modulus, taking it out means it can be positive or negative doesn't it? So is it not a important part of the equation, or am I wrong? If so please let me know

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing `modulus` and `absolute value`.

Comment: But in my textbook it says that e.g for y=|x| , we have for y=x, x>0 and for y=-x x<0, so I applied this same concept to the questions @Bernard

Comment: This has nothing to do with a modulus (which is an arithmetic notion).

Comment: @Bernard is my title more accurate now?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By triangle inequality we have: $$ 2=|x+1|+ |-4x+3|\geq |-3x+4|$$

so $$-2\leq -3x+4\leq 2\implies x\in [{2\over 3},1]\implies x>0$$
so $$|-4x+3|=-x+1$$

1. case $$-x+1 = -4x+3\implies x=2/3$$
2. case $$x-1 = -4x+3\implies x=4/5$$

Comment: I was wondering what does triangle inequality mean?

Comment: For all $a,b$ we have: $$|a|+|b|\geq |a+b|$$

Answer (score 1):

On $-1 \leq x < \frac{3}{4}$,

$2-(x+1) = -4x+3 \iff 3x = 2 \iff x = \frac{2}{3}$